# Hybridauth set access token invalid

Tags: php, android, kotlin, google-oauth, hybridauth

For full context, I have an android application which communicates with a php server. I am able to successfully login to a google account using this function from android level (kotlin):

```
val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestServerAuthCode(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build()
        val googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(requireContext(), gso)
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_social_login, container, false)

        val googleSignUpButton = view.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.googleSignUpButton)
        someActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
                ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
        ) { result: ActivityResult ->
            val data: Intent? = result.data
                val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
                try {
                    val account = task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)!!
                    validateToken(account.idToken!!)
                } catch (e: ApiException) {
                    Log.w("SocialLoginFragment", "Google sign in failed", e)
                }



        }
    private fun firebaseAuthWithGoogle(idToken: String) {

        val credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken, null)
        auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(requireActivity()) { task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                        val user = auth.currentUser
                        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), user?.email, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        
                    } else {
                        Log.w("SocialLoginFragment", "signInWithCredential:failure", task.exception)
                    }
                }
    }
```

the **"validateToken" **calls the GET request https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token= and verifies if the id_token is valid, which is the case. **"firebaseAuthWithGoogle" **just shows the user's mail in Toast.  but when i pass that id token to my PHP backend server, it returns Invalid credentials, to be specific this my Hybridauth snippet

```
$idToken = "ID_TOKEN"; //same id token generated previously from android after login success
$clientId = "CLIENT_ID";
$secretKey = "SECRET_KEY";
$callback = "https://baseurl/index.php/sociallogin/social/callback/?hauth.done=Google";
$config = [
    'callback' => $callback,
    'keys' => ['id' => $clientId, 'secret' => $secretKey],
    'scope' => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile', 
    'authorize_url_parameters' => [
      'approval_prompt' => 'force', 
      'access_type' => 'offline'
    ]
];

try {
    $hybridauth = new Hybridauth\Hybridauth($config);
    $adapter = new \Hybridauth\Provider\Google($config);
    
    
    $adapter->setAccessToken([
        'access_token' => $idToken
    ]);
    $profile = $adapter->getUserProfile();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

expected output:
user info

current output:

```
Caught exception: Signed API request to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo has returned an error. HTTP error 401. Raw Provider API response: {
  "error": "invalid_request",
  "error_description": "Invalid Credentials"
}.
```

I could've sworn that it worked perfectly earlier this year.
Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:

I have resolved the problem by using *authorization code* instead of id token to get the access token, i was confusing between id token and access token. Here is my updated code for both kotlin and php sides

```
Android:
someActivityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
                ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
        ) { result: ActivityResult ->
.... 
val authCode = account?.serverAuthCode
                    Log.d(TAG,"$authCode") //i have copied the console output into the php code 
}}
```

Php:

```
$config = ....
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId('1000593837042-il6hm8f4b3grahtpo4c2s0esggagl2dn.apps.googleusercontent.com');
$client->setClientSecret('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');
$authCode= //here i paste my authCode from the android console
$tokenArray = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
try {
    $accessToken = $tokenArray['access_token'];

    $hybridauth = new Hybridauth\Hybridauth($config);
    $adapter = new \Hybridauth\Provider\Google($config);
    $adapter->setAccessToken([
        'access_token' => $accessToken
    ]);
    $profile = $adapter->getUserProfile();
    echo $profile->email //outputs the email ;
```

if there's anything still unclear, feel free to reach out.

Comment: an id token is not an access token.  'access_token' => $idToken